Power analysis for three-level multilevel models in R
For a study in a social science setting - where huge number of participants are not easily available - I'm trying to do a power analysis for a three-level multilevel design.
There are few packages available for two-level multilevel power analysis, such as simr or MLPowSim. Those packages have some advantages e.g. easy simulation designs and thorough tutorials, however, those packages focus on two level multilevel designs. Three-level designs are not possible.
The model I want to work with has a more complicated structure.
A stripped down version could look something like this. Where I have random intercept and slope on level 2 and a random intercept on level 3. X represents a level 1 predictor, W a level 2 predictor and Z a level 3 predictor.
Level 1 (individual-level):
Y_ijk = β_0jk + β_1jk*X_ijk + r_ijk

Level 2 (group-level):
β_0jk = γ_00k + γ_01k*W_jk + u_0jk
β_1jk = γ_10k + γ_11k*W_jk + u_1jk

Level 3 (higher group-level):
γ_00k = δ_000 + δ_001*Z_k + v_00k
γ_01k = δ_010 + δ_011*Z_k
γ_10k = δ_100 + δ_101*Z_k
γ_11k = δ_110 + δ_111*Z_k

Combined model (with interactions):
Y_ijk = (δ_000 + δ_001*Z_k + v_00k) + (δ_010 + δ_011*Z_k)*W_jk + u_0jk +
        ((δ_100 + δ_101*Z_k) + (δ_110 + δ_111*Z_k)*W_jk + u_1jk)*X_ijk + r_ijk


My final model includes more predictors and is slightly more complicated.
How would I conduct a power analysis for such a model?
Would a custom simulation be the best approach? Has someone some experience with this kind of power analysis?
Arend, Matthias G., and Thomas Schäfer. „Statistical power in two-level models: A tutorial based on Monte Carlo simulation“. Psychological Methods 24, Nr. 1 (Februar 2019): 1–19. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000195.

I haven't tried it, but an R package "powerlmm" seems to be able to handle power calculations for a 3-level model: https://rpsychologist.com/introducing-powerlmm

I have tried that packaged. And there is even a three-level vignette. However, the packaged is no longer supported, and I can't even get the example to run.
https://github.com/rpsychologist/powerlmm/tree/master/vignettes

Welcome to Cross Validated :) You said "How would I conduct a power analysis for such a model?" . But the power to do what ? What effect size (and for which variable) do you want to detect ? @Sointu I am in the same boat as Linus... I used powerlmm a while ago, but gave up and didn't get any response from the developer/maintainer.  Anyway, I would approach this as a simulation. It is fairly straightforward. I'll try to post an answer a bit later.

Well, we have a theoretically driven model and will use experience and data from similar studies to determine the effect sizes of the different predictors. Primary goal is to gain insight in how the power for each of the predictor behaves to the numbers of observations on the different levels. We do this so that during the data collection we can aim to e.g. sample as much L1 units as possible.

Sorry, I didn't know the package is discontinued! I'd also like to know how to calculate power for 3-level models.

@Sointu Just to let you know that I've just posted an answer. I hope it helps you both :)

To compute power for a linear mixed model by simulation, one general approach is:

Simulate data under the alternative hypothesis - ie., with whatever effect size you are interested in detecting.
Fit the model.
Extract the p-value
Repeat many times
Calculate the proportion of times a "significant" p-value is obtained

The main difficulty with calculating power for mixed models by simulation is handling problems with convergence at step 2 above. There needs to be some code which catches non-convergence and convergence to a singular fit. Arguably the singular fits should be included, but the non-convergent ones should definitely not.
So, here is an example with the features that you want:
We will attempt to calculate power to detect an effect size of 0.5 for the level 3 predictor.
We are going to require quite a lot of parameters:
We will specify the number of level 1 units per level 2 unit, the number of level 2 units per level 3 unit and the number of level 3 units.
n_level1 <- 20 
n_level2 <- 20  
n_level3 <- 10 

Then we need the fixed effects parameters
beta_level1 <- 1.5
beta_level2 <- 0.8
beta_level3 <- 0.5

The we need the standard deviations of the random effects:
sigma_level1 <- 1  
sigma_level2 <- 0.5
sigma_level3 <- 0.3
sigma_slope_level2 <- 0.2 #random slopes SD for beta_level2

Then number of simulations and the significance level
n_sim <- 25
alpha <- 0.05

And finally placeholders to store a vector of p-values from the fitted models, and (for investigations) a list containing all the fitted models
p_values <- numeric(n_sim)
fitted_models <- list()

Then we will generate the data and fit the model n_sim times.
set.seed(1)
n <- n_level1 * n_level2 * n_level3     # total level 1 observations

for (i in 1:n_sim) {
      # Group IDs for level 2 and level 3
    level3 <- rep(1:n_level3, each = (n_level2 * n_level1) / n_level3)
    level2 <- rep(rep(1:n_level2, each = n_level1), times = n_level3)
    
    # Predictors for each level
    x_level1 <- rnorm(n)
    x_level2 <- rnorm(n_level2)
    x_level3 <- rnorm(n_level3)
    
    # Expand the level 2 and level 3 predictors
    x_level2_expanded <- x_level2[level2]
    x_level3_expanded <- x_level3[level3]
    
    # Random intercepts and random slopes
    random_intercept_level3 <- rnorm(n_level3, mean = 0, sd = sigma_level3)
    random_intercept_level2 <- rnorm(n_level2, mean = 0, sd = sigma_level2)
    random_slope_level2 <- rnorm(n_level2, mean = 0, sd = sigma_slope_level2)
    
    # Expand random intercepts and slopes to match the number of level 1 units
    intercept_level3 <- random_intercept_level3[level3]
    intercept_level2 <- random_intercept_level2[level2]
    slope_level2 <- random_slope_level2[level2]
    
    # Generate unit residuals
    residuals_level1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = sigma_level1)

    # Generate the outcome
    y <- beta_level1 * x_level1 + 
         (beta_level2 + slope_level2) * x_level2_expanded + 
         beta_level3 * x_level3_expanded +
         intercept_level3 + 
         intercept_level2 + 
         residuals_level1

    data <- data.frame(y = y, 
                       x_level1 = x_level1, 
                       x_level2 = x_level2_expanded, 
                       x_level3 = x_level3_expanded, 
                       level2 = factor(level2), 
                       level3 = factor(level3))
    
    # Fit the model

    model <- lmer(y ~ x_level1 + x_level2 + x_level3 + 
                      (1 | level3) + (1 + x_level2 | level3:level2), 
                      data = data)

    # Store the fitted model and p-values
    fitted_models[[i]] <- model    
    p_values[i] <- coef(summary(model))["x_level3", "Pr(>|t|)"]
}

Having fitted the model and extracted what we need n_sim times, all thats is left is the trivial exercise of calculating the power:
> mean(p_values < 0.05)
[1] 0.56


So in this case the power is 56%
As mentioned above, if you find that the parameters you use result in singular fits and non-convergence, you will need to do something about that. One fairly easy approach is to test for singularity or non-convergence, and skip that particular simulation. That's not too hard to do, but since that is very much a programming issue, I will leave that to you. But here is a little helper function that I wrote a while ago to check convergence.
# helper function
# Has the model converged ?

hasConverged <- function (mm) {
  # Function takes a fitted model and returns as follows:
  # -1 if the model fails to converge
  #  0 if the model converged to a singular fit
  #  1 otherwise

  # Note, if using `lmerTest` you will need to change this line 
  # (or just comment it out!)
  if ( !class(mm)[1] == "lmerMod") stop("Error must pass a lmerMod object") 
  
  retval <- NULL
  
  if(is.null(unlist(mm@optinfo$conv$lme4))) {
    retval = 1
  }
  else {
    if (isSingular(mm)) {
      retval = 0
    } else {
      retval = -1
    }
  }
  return(retval)
}

you can see how I used in in a vaguely similar situation as this at the following threads:
Obtaining correlation between random-effects separately for 2 groups
Can fixed-effects become biased due to random structure misspecification
Lastly I will say that there is an alternative way of simulating the data. The approach I used above works pretty well in my experience, but a more sophisticated way to do it is by using the general formula for a mixed model:
$$\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X \beta} + \textbf{Zb} + \epsilon,$$
where:

$\mathbf{Y}$ is the response vector of length $n \times 1$, where $n$ is the number of observations.
$\mathbf{X}$ is the fixed-effects design matrix of dimensions $n \times p$, where $p$ is the number of fixed-effect parameters.
$\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is the vector of fixed-effects coefficients of length $p \times 1$.
$\mathbf{Z}$ is the random-effects design matrix of dimensions $n \times q$, where $q$ is the number of random effects.
$\mathbf{b}$ is the vector of random effects of length $q \times 1$.
$\epsilon$ is the vector of residual errors of length $n \times 1$, often assumed to follow $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I})$, where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the residual errors.

$\mathbf{X}$ can be easily formed, as it is just the usual model matrix of fixed effects. The difficult part is to correctly form $\mathbf{Z}$, but I have found a neat trick to do that, where you first form $\mathbf{X}$ using model.matrix and them obtain $\mathbf{Z}$ by creating a mixed model formula object using lme4::lFormula and then use the fact that the transpose of $\mathbf{Z}$ is saved in the formula object and can be easily obtained with t(as.matrix(foo$reTrms$Zt)) where foo is the formula object obtained with lme4::lFormula(). I did this in both of the linked answers above, so please refer to those for more details.

@Sointu you're very welcome. I have just updated it with a function for checking convergence. Haven't tested it for a while, so I hope it still works !!

Maybe I've missed it but your simulation seems to assume all covariances are zero. Couldn't that invalidate the result if they are actually far from zero?

@Roland absolutely right (+1), and that's not the only shortcoming. Covariances between the fixed effects are absent, as is the correlation between the random intercepts and slopes. The grouping structure is also somewhat simplistic, as all the groups (at each level) have exactly the same size. And there is no handling of convergence issues. I deal with some of these issues (in particular, correlations between random effects and convergence issues) in the two answers I linked to. To handle all the issues, I might need to write a package !

Another thing I’m unsure with your solution is that when doing a power analysis we usually want to define the power for standardized effect sizes. So, we would set a given beta to e.g. .2 and say this is the standardized beta. However, this does not hold true, when we add an error term, right?
$y=b ∗X+e$
Creating a y depending on a Beta and an error term has the effects, that the y has no longer the expected variance. And thus the effect of B is no longer standardized, right?
Because if:
$Var(y)=Var(b ∗ X)+Var(e)$
Then this must hold true:
$Var(e)=1−Var(b ∗X)$

@Linus I am not generally a fan of standardisation, and I’ve done power analysis mostly with data that are unstandardised, and whether to standardise is often determined by the area of research. Obviously, if you do want to standardise, it’s fairly trivial to adapt the code to do so.

I might be mistaken (way out of my comfort zone here;)), but I don't think it's trivial. We can not simply set the beta in your code to a certain level because the variances of dependent and independent variables must equal to 1. This includes the variance of the error term. If we simply add the variance of the error term like we do now, ()=1−(∗) no longer holds true. Thus, the betas are strictly speaking no longer standardized.

@Linus maybe trivial isn’t the right word but simulating ALL the data for the fixed effects together at the same time using linear algebra (ie specifying the variance- covariance matrix….actually just a correlation matrix for standardised data) rather than one variable at a time , is fairly easy and should address all your concerns (unless I’m am misunderstanding you). Feel free to ask a new question specifying that you want standardised variables, and I will try to have a go at it :). But based on how this question is asked, I think this answer answers it :) ….(Cont)

…(Continued). One reason why I didn’t use the VCV matrix and linear algebra in my answer is that I have found when teaching this, that it’s often more understandable doing it variable by variable.

@Linus I''ve been thinking about this a bit more. I don't have access to a computer at the moment but maybe something like this would do what you want: x_level1 <- scale(x_level1) and likewise for the others, and then just adjust the unit residuals so that $y$ has variance of 1, something like sigma_residual <- sqrt(1 - var_beta_x) where var_beta_x <- var(beta_level1 * x_level1 + (beta_level2 + slope_level2) * x_level2_expanded + beta_level3 * x_level3_expanded) which is the variance of the linear predictor. Obv there would need to be code to scale the coefficients if var_beta_x is > 1

@Linus rather than you posting a new question, I will have a go at a standardised solution and post a new anwer here when done. I might as well go "all-in" and handle covariance among the explanatory variables, and between the random effects (I will expand the model and have random slopes too), and also handle the convergence issues. If I can find an easy way to simulate the grouping structure to allow non-equal group sizes at each level, then I will do that too. Could be wishful thinking, but I will have a go

@RobertLong Thanks for your clarifications! An example also including non-equal grouping structure would be very much appreciated. I have been thinking about how one could simulate that as well. It is quite a brainteaser! So long I have not come up with something useful when not using the general formula - that's why I was trying to understand it in more detail:)

Hi @Linus, I've got the unequal group structure working already :) Just need to handle the rest - hopefully I can get that done over the weekend.  If you want to find out more about using the general formula take a look at those two answers of mine that I linked to in my answer above. Finally (for now) you might also find my answer in the following link useful, as it creates $Z$ manually (albeit for multiple membership models, but the principles behind creating $Z$ are the same - it's purpose is to map the relevant random effects, $\mathbf{b}$, onto the response). $\mathbf{Y}$.../Continued/...

/Continued....and here's that link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487039/multiple-membership-vs-crossed-random-effects/487047#487047

@RobertLong Have you had a chance to have a look at the standardized solution? I would also be interested in your solution of the unequal group structure. Many thanks :)
